# Run the jar file using exec function in php

Tags: php, jar, exec, server

I try to execute the jar file in php

I'v tried is exec working
with :

```
       echo exec('whoami');
```

i got response nt authority

also tested with :

```
      if(function_exists('exec')) {
      echo "exec is enabled";
       }
```

so it probably works?

I am trying to run a file called tester.php
when i include it, its working..

When i try to execute Java jar file ..it its not working.
I tried :

```
exec('java -jar learning.jar', $output);
exec('java -jar /home/public_html/path/learning.jar', $output);
exec('java -jar http:/www.global.com/path/learning.jar', $output);
```

not working

It working fine in a local-server ..but the live server ,is not working ..

Comment: Let me guess public server does not have java preinstalled.

Comment: and one more Thing ..exec function read the PHP file and it not run the file ..it only ready and display in a array format...weather Java necessary to run the file